# Cloud Pub/Sub subscriber repeats messages over 600ms

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

We recently integrated google pubsub into our app, and some of our long running tasks are now under problem, as they take more than 1 minute sometimes. We have configured our subscriber's ack deadline to 600 seconds, yet, anything that is taking more than `600ms`, is being retried by pubsub.

this is our config:

`gcloud pubsub subscriptions describe name`

```
ackDeadlineSeconds: 600
expirationPolicy: {}
messageRetentionDuration: 604800s
```

Not sure what is the issue. Most of our tasks will get repeated because of this

Comment: In your description you specify `600ms`, is this right or are you talking about `600 seconds`?

Comment: @NahuelVarelaBlanco I have set the ack delivery timeout at 600s, but unless I give a 200 status code within 600ms, PubSub is resending the message. Sometimes it's sending the same message three-four times, immediately on being queued, without waiting for an ack.

Comment: I have updated my answer, also in the FAQs it is stated that: "Cloud Pub/Sub may batch messages internally and a partially acknowledged batch will be fully redelivered."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pub/Sub has a built in [At-least-once](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery) delivery system which will retry messages that were not acknowledged. In this case, after 600s have passed, the message you first sent becomes unacknowledged, thus Pub/Sub retries the message. It will keep retrying it for 600s until it reaches the `messageRetentionDuration` or you acknowledge it.

Keep in mind that it's specified in the documentation that your subscriber should be idempotent. So, making your code be able to handle multiple messages should be the best approach to this issue.

You could also decrease the `messageRetentionDuration` to `600s`(it's minimum) so anything that passes the 10 min mark will not be retried.

Also, it is stated in the [FAQs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq#duplicates) that:

> **Why are there too many duplicate messages?**
>
> Cloud Pub/Sub guarantees at-least-once message delivery, which means
>   that occasional duplicates are to be expected. However, a high rate of
>   duplicates may indicate that the client is not acknowledging messages
>   within the configured `ack_deadline_seconds`, and Cloud Pub/Sub is
>   retrying the message delivery. This can be observed in the [monitoring
>   metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics).
>   `pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/pull_ack_message_operation_count`
>   for pull subscriptions, and
>   `pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/push_request_count` for push
>   subscriptions. Look for elevated expired or `webhook_timeout` values in
>   the `/response_code`. This is particularly likely if there are many
>   small messages, since Cloud Pub/Sub may batch messages internally and
>   a partially acknowledged batch will be fully redelivered.
>
> Another possibility is that the subscriber is not acknowledging some
>   messages because the code path processing those specific messages
>   fails, and the Acknowledge call is never made; or the push endpoint
>   never responds or responds with an error.